# How to make a special expandable phrase in bash?

Tags: bash, bash-expansion

I find myself doing `<command> --help | grep <feature>` very very often everyday. I was wondering if it was possible to make something like `^^` that expands to `"--help | grep"` and then I do this:

```
ls ^^ size
```

That would execute the following:

```
ls --help | grep size
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With `zsh`, you'd use a *global* alias:

```
$ alias -g '^^=--help|grep --color -i'
$ ls ^^ size
     --block-size=SIZE      scale sizes by SIZE before printing them; e.g.,
                              '--block-size=M' prints sizes in units of
                              1,048,576 bytes; see SIZE format below
 -h, --human-readable       with -l and/or -s, print human readable sizes
 -s, --size                 print the allocated size of each file, in blocks
 -S                         sort by file size, largest first
     --sort=WORD            sort by WORD instead of name: none (-U), size (-S),
 -T, --tabsize=COLS         assume tab stops at each COLS instead of 8
The SIZE argument is an integer and optional unit (example: 10K is 10*1024)
```

With `bash`, you may be able to use *history expansion* which is one that happens early enough in the shell syntax parsing that it can work at substituting a pipe:

1. Prime the history with a the text you want to substitute and a special character you're unlikely to use otherwise (like `£` here that happens to be on my keyboard):

   ```
    $ --help $(: £)|grep
    bash: --help: command not found
    Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
    Try 'grep --help' for more information.
   ```
2. Then using history expansion to retrieve that:

   ```
   $ ls !?£? size
   ls --help $(: £)|grep size
        --block-size=SIZE  scale sizes by SIZE before printing them; e.g.,
                             '--block-size=M' prints sizes in units of
    -h, --human-readable   with -l and/or -s, print human readable sizes
    -s, --size             print the allocated size of each file, in blocks
    -S                     sort by file size, largest first
        --sort=WORD        sort by WORD instead of name: none (-U), size (-S),
    -T, --tabsize=COLS     assume tab stops at each COLS instead of 8
   ```

Or you could have `readline` expand `--help|grep` upon some key or key sequence press. For that to apply to `bash` only (and not other applications like `gdb` using readline), you can use the `bind` bash builtin command which is `bash`'s API to configuring `readline`, for instance in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
bind '"^^": "--help|grep "'
```

Or add to your `~/.inputrc` (readline's configuration file):

```
$if Bash
"^^": "--help|grep "
$endif
```

(there are other  shells like `rc` or `es` that  use readline and where doing that binding could make sense but AFAICT, they do not set the `rl_readline_name` variable before invoking `readline` so you won't be able to add some `$if` statements for them (they would show as `other` like all applications that use readline without telling it their application name)).

Note that you need to enter the second `^` within half a second (by default) after the first one for the substitution to occur.

Comment: Can you explain the readline solution a little bit more?! where should I add that binding? on what applications will that binding expand?

Comment: @yukashimahuksay, see edit

Answer (score 17):

You can use a bash function for that:

Put the following in your ~/.bashrc:

```
qh() {
    type -all "$1" ; { man "$1" || "$1" --help ;} | egrep -i -- "$2"
}
```

When you save your `bashrc`  do `source ~/.bashrc` then you can do:

```
$ qh ls size
      --block-size=SIZE      scale sizes by SIZE before printing them; e.g.,
                               '--block-size=M' prints sizes in units of
  -h, --human-readable       with -l and/or -s, print human readable sizes
  -s, --size                 print the allocated size of each file, in blocks
  -S                         sort by file size, largest first
      --sort=WORD            sort by WORD instead of name: none (-U), size (-S),
  -T, --tabsize=COLS         assume tab stops at each COLS instead of 8
```

Comment: you should quote $1 and $2. I'd change this into :  `qh () {  type -all "$1" ; { "$1" --help || man "$1" ;} | egrep -i -- "$2" ;}`  # hence you could:    qh ls size  ,   qh ls "something|another" etc. the (optionnal) `type -all "$1"` also add the info about $1: it says if you will be launching an alias, a function, a command, etc.And it gives out info from man "$1" if the command $1 didn't have the option "--help" (this happens sometimes)

Comment: @OlivierDulac Can you please explain a bit more about type -all "$1"? In what case will it be necessity?

Comment: My version of type (kubuntu 16.04) knows about `-a`, but doesn't say anything about `-l` or `-all`, but the function does work.

Answer (score 8):

You could use readline bindings:

add a line like

```
"^^": "--help | grep "
```

to your ~/.inputrc

Then press ^X ^R in your term, and the binding will be activated.

Keying `ls ^^` will now result in `ls --help | grep`.

Comment: I answered before i saw, that Stephane had added the readline solution. I deleted my answer, but then undeletes, when I saw the comment asking about details for the readline solution

Comment: I've now added some more on that in my answer.

Comment: Targeted answers like yours, and comprehensive ones like Stéphane's, both have their place. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 5):

## Using `less` to view the help message

You may find it useful to see the surrounding context of the lines that match your search query.

```
hh () { "${1}" --help | less -p "${2}" ; }
```

The syntax to call this `bash` function is similar to the function `qh` in @tgwtdt's answer, with the first argument being the command to examine, and the second argument being the search term.  For example:

```
hh ls size
```

```
hh ls "symbolic link"
```

This opens the full help message in `less`, highlights every instance of the search term, and scrolls to the first instance of the search term.  You can then press `n` to scroll forward to the next line containing the search term, `n` again for the next, and so on.  To scroll back to a previous instance, press `N`.  Use the `Home`, `End`,`Page Up`, `Page Down`, `Up Arrow`, and `Down Arrow` keys for general navigation.  Press `q` or `Q` to exit `less` and return to the command line.

Answer (score 3):

I liked the solution by @tgwtdt, so I enhanced it a bit.

This does the same thing, but does a little to handle errors and also tries to process built-ins.

qh uses () instead of {} so qh1() and out are local (in a subshell).

```
function qh () (
    function qh1 () {
      out="$(help "$1" 2>&1 )"
      [ $? -ne 0 ] && return 1
      echo "$out"
    }

    type -all "$1" ; { qh1 "$1" || "$1" --help 2>/dev/null || man "$1" 2>/dev/null ;} | egrep -i -- "$2"
)
```